# How to put a background image in a figure (using matlab GUIDE)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

Currently I am working on a matlab GUIDE and would like to include an image as the background of the GUI. May I know how can I include a static image in the GUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `axes` graphical control:

```
 f= figure()
 a = axes('Position',[0 0 1 1],'Units','Normalized');
 imshow('peppers.png','Parent',a);
```

You can put anything you want above the axes:

```
 uicontrol('Style','text','Units','Normalized','Position',[0.1 0.1 0.3 0.6],'String','Example');
```

You can do it in GUIDE as well, simple stretch an axes over the whole figure manually.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is one another way of doing this.
Go to
                                 `function untitled_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)` function and right between `handles.output = hObject;` and 
`guidata(hObject, handles);` write down the following code

`% create an axes that spans the whole gui

ah = axes('unit', 'normalized', 'position', [0 0 1 1]);

% import the background image and show it on the axes

bg = imread('your_image.jpg'); imagesc(bg);

% prevent plotting over the background and turn the axis off

set(ah,'handlevisibility','off','visible','off')

% making sure the background is behind all the other uicontrols
uistack(ah, 'bottom');`

[image: Before]
[image: AfteG]